# Determine (in the next page) which anchor tag was clicked (the anchor tag in the previous page)

Tags: php, anchor

Sorry for the confusing/vague question title. I couldn't come up with a better one.

***THE SITUATION***

Suppose a page `abc.php` has a set of anchor tags.

```
<a href="xxx.php">AAA</a>
<a href="xxx.php">BBB</a>
<a href="xxx.php">CCC</a>
```

If I click on `BBB`, is there way to find out inside `xxx.php` that `BBB` was the link which brought it here? In the same way if `CCC` is clicked, can it be known in `xxx.php` that the redirection took place because of `CCC` link?

In a nutshell, I'm looking for a set of links redirecting to a single page and in that page determine which link caused the redirection.

**PS** : I know I can do that using **`query strings`** but I would prefer to avoid them as much as possible. Also I would also like it to be in PHP only (if possible, i.e. server side; something like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to expose query strings on the client (I don't see a reason for avoiding them for the scope of your problem) an you want all to be performed on the server side you can try using the rewriting rules on Apache.

Something like

```
<a href="xxx_aaa">AAA</a>
<a href="xxx_bbb">BBB</a>
<a href="xxx_ccc">CCC</a>
```

And rewrite a rule in your .htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule ^xxx_(.*)$ xxx.php?id=$1
```

And within your script you could know where it came with

```
$_REQUEST['id']
```

Yes, at the end you are using a query string even if you are not exposing it, but solutions like $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will not work.

Comment: +1. This sounds good. But I'll keep this as a last resort if nothing better comes up

Comment: Since there haven't been any more answers, I'll go by your solution.